# Разделение строки по разделителю и преобразование в числа

Tags: python, файлы, кодировка, unicode

День добрый!

Есть `.txt` файл который содержит строки вида:

```
8415778000|8415778099
```

Мне нужно записать все числа а промежутке от 1-го числа до 2-го. Я написал вот такой скрипт.

```
f = open('pool.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    a, b = line.split('|', 1)
    b = int(b.strip())
    a = int(a.strip())
    print (str(a))
    while a <= b:
        a += 1
        print(str(a))
```

Но при выполнении он выдает ошибку:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):    
      File "*/1.py", line 5, in <module>    
       a = int(a.strip())    
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xef\xbb\xbf8415778000'
```

Я не могу понять почему, помогите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примените параметр `encoding='utf_8_sig'` в функции `open()`:

```
f = open('pool.txt', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

так как ваш файл кодирован в кодировке *UTF-8 s BOM* (BOM - Byte Order Mark), где первые 3 байты *всегда те же самые* (для обозначения вот этой кодировки).

---

*Примечание:*

Вместо

```
f = open('pool.txt', encoding='utf_8_sig')
for line in f.readlines():
    a, b = line.split('|', 1)
    ....
    ....
```

лучше писать

```
with open('pool.txt', encoding='utf_8_sig') as some_name:
    for line in some_name:
         a, b = line.split('|', 1)
         ....
         ....
```

т.к. после выхода из блока `with` будет файл автоматически закрыт (кроме других преимуществ).

Answer (score 3):

`\xef\xbb\xbf` - это [Маркер последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Можно попробовать следующее:

```
f = open("pool.txt")
data = f.read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8")
```